# Submit form with multiple entries with the same name

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

Consider each entry in a form has the following field-names:

- product_name
- product_license
- product_version

I want to make it possible to add multiple products within one form. I was thinking about something like the following, where the trailing integers correspond to the ID of the specific product in my database (which means that they don't have to be in a sequence. It could also be *1, 3, 19*):

- product_name_1
- product_license_1
- product_version_1
- product_name_2
- product_license_2
- product_version_2

If I were to submit this form via the `POST`-method, I would (for instance) get the following results:

```
$_POST['product_name_1'] = 'computer';
$_POST['product_license_1'] = '$_FA_MySuperCoolLicenseForAComputer';
$_POST['product_version_1'] = 'Computer 1.0';
// And so on...
```

Under normal circumstances I would have submitted the entries as an array (including the ID in an additional hidden input-field) like in this example:

```
<input type='hidden' name='product_id[]' value='1'>
<input type='text' name='product_name[]'>
<input type='text' name='product_license[]'>
<input type='text' name='product_version[]'>
<!-- Repeat for every product in the form -->

<?php
$_POST['product_id'][0]   = '1';
$_POST['product_id'][1]   = '2';
$_POST['product_name'][0] = 'computer';
$_POST['product_name'][1] = 'screen';
```

However, this is **not** possible for me. *Don't ask why.*

My question is: Am I able to iterate through every of these elements so I can save all products in my database at once? I always need the ID of the entry plus every other field. How could I retrieve them?

It's probably quite easy and I'm just too dumb to see it right now. I hope you can prove me right ;)

Comment: Add _1, _2, _3 to the end of the input's name/ id. Add new products via a javascript button that also appends the _2, _3 etc. And when submitting the form also send the counter so you know how many products where submited. Then, using a for loop, get the data from all of them.

Comment: @TraianTatic The counter is a good idea, I haven't thought of that yet. However this is not only a "create new"-form, but also an "edit"-form. So it can easily be possible that the id's aren't consecutive (`_1`, `_2`, `_8`, ...), so using a loop from `_1` to `_$count` will not work properly.

Comment: So what.. you wish to have a multiple products edit at the same time? You'll just fetch the list of products form the database and select the one you want to edit. No?

Comment: I want to be able to make multiple edits at once. So I need to load all products (possibly add some new ones), make changes to them (or not) and save those changes.

Comment: I have some kind of [demo](http://mercatio.ro/adauga.php).
Write me after you saw and understand it, because I won't let it up for that long. Click "Adauga campuri" to see how it adds more products fields. For editing existing ones just use another page or something, don't make a mess; or at least split the views for add/ edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate with simple loop

```
 $array=array();
 for($i=1;$i<$limit;$i++){
  $product=array(
    "product_id"=>$_POST["product_id_".$i];
    "product_anme"=>$_POST["product_name_".$i];
    //etc..
  );
  $array[]=$product;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make an array on the basis of the form submission, and send it to the method which inserting the data to the db.

Something Like :

```
<input type='text' name='product_name[]'>
<input type='text' name='product_license[]'>
<input type='text' name='product_version[]'>


<?php
//receiving Part 

for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["product_name"]);$i++)
{
    $arr[]["product_id"]=$i;
    $arr[]["product_name_".$id]=$_POST["product_name"][$i];
    $arr[]["product_license_".$id]=$_POST["product_license"][$i];
}

?>
```

Here in form there is no Product ID is there and been calculated at the PHP end.

Comment: As stated in my question, I usually would've done this, but I can't. The system I'm using won't allow multiple inputs with the same name (even if there's a `[]` at the end) for some strange reasons.

Comment: Let me tell you one thing that, your code is not able to receive multiple value. You need to use loop or anything like JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT to replicate the input fields multiple time to take the input multiple times. I have written the code on the basis of that the HTML part is OK and taking multiple inputs.

Comment: I know that your HTML is correct and I *am* using Javascript to replicate the fields. But neither of this does change the fact that I can't just append a `[]` to the name. I need to do this in another way.